# Slice a PowerShell array into groups of smaller arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, data-partitioning

I would like to convert a single array into a group of smaller arrays, based on a variable.  So, `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` would become `0,1,2`,`3,4,5`,`6,7,8`,`9` when the size is 3.

My current approach:

```
$ids=@(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
$size=3

0..[math]::Round($ids.count/$size) | % { 

    # slice first elements
    $x = $ids[0..($size-1)]

    # redefine array w/ remaining values
    $ids = $ids[$size..$ids.Length]

    # return elements (as an array, which isn't happening)
    $x

} | % { "IDS: $($_ -Join ",")" }
```

Produces:

```
IDS: 0
IDS: 1
IDS: 2
IDS: 3
IDS: 4
IDS: 5
IDS: 6
IDS: 7
IDS: 8
IDS: 9
```

I would like it to be:

```
IDS: 0,1,2
IDS: 3,4,5
IDS: 6,7,8
IDS: 9
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're just assigning `$ids` to `$x` and sending it down the stream to be iterated by `| % {`.

Comment: Use `,$x` instead of just `$x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `,$x` instead of just `$x`.

The `about_Operators` section in the documentation has this:

```
, Comma operator                                                  
   As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary
   operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the
   comma before the member.
```

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completeness:

```
function Slice-Array
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [String[]]$Item,
        [int]$Size=10
    )
    BEGIN { $Items=@()}
    PROCESS {
        foreach ($i in $Item ) { $Items += $i }
    }
    END {
        0..[math]::Floor($Items.count/$Size) | ForEach-Object { 
            $x, $Items = $Items[0..($Size-1)], $Items[$Size..$Items.Length]; ,$x
        } 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) | Slice-Array -Size 3 | ForEach-Object { "IDs: $($_ -Join ",")" }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cls
$ids=@(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
$size=3

<# 
Manual Selection:
    $ids | Select-Object -First 3 -Skip 0
    $ids | Select-Object -First 3 -Skip 3
    $ids | Select-Object -First 3 -Skip 6
    $ids | Select-Object -First 3 -Skip 9
#>

# Select via looping
$idx = 0
while ($($size * $idx) -lt $ids.Length){

    $group = $ids | Select-Object -First $size -skip ($size * $idx)
    $group -join ","
    $idx ++
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Craig himself has conveniently wrapped the splitting (partitioning) functionality in a **[robust function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45949091/45375)**:

Let me offer a **better-performing evolution of it** (PSv3+ syntax, **renamed to `Split-Array`**), which:

- more efficiently collects the input objects using an extensible `System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` collection.
- doesn't *modify* the collection during splitting, and instead extracts *ranges* of elements from it.

```bash
function Split-Array {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String[]] $InputObject
        ,
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int] $Size = 10
    )
    begin   { $items = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object] }
    process { $items.AddRange($InputObject) }
    end {
      $chunkCount = [Math]::Floor($items.Count / $Size)
      foreach ($chunkNdx in 0..($chunkCount-1)) {
        , $items.GetRange($chunkNdx * $Size, $Size).ToArray()
      }
      if ($chunkCount * $Size -lt $items.Count) {
        , $items.GetRange($chunkCount * $Size, $items.Count - $chunkCount * $Size).ToArray()
      }
    }
}
```

With small input collections, the optimization won't matter much, but once you get into the thousands of elements, the speed-up can be dramatic:

To give a rough sense of the performance improvement, using [`Time-Command`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

```bash
$ids = 0..1e4 # 10,000 numbers
$size = 3 # chunk size

Time-Command { $ids | Split-Array -size $size }, # optimized
             { $ids | Slice-Array -size $size }  # original
```

Sample result from a single-core Windows 10 VM with Windows 5.1 (the absolute times aren't important, but the factors are):

```
Command                        Secs (10-run avg.) TimeSpan         Factor
-------                        ------------------ --------         ------
$ids | Split-Array -size $size 0.150              00:00:00.1498207 1.00
$ids | Slice-Array -size $size 10.382             00:00:10.3820590 69.30
```

Note how the unoptimized function was almost 70 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

To add an *explanation* to [Bill Stewart's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948916/45375):

**Outputting a collection such as an array<sup>[1]</sup> either *implicitly* or using `return` sends its elements *individually* through the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)**; that is, the **collection is *enumerated*** (unrolled):

```
# Count objects received.
PS> (1..3 | Measure-Object).Count
3   # Array elements were sent *individually* through the pipeline.
```

**Using the unary form of [`,` (comma; the array-construction operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-) to prevent enumeration** is a conveniently concise, though somewhat obscure *workaround*:

```
PS> (, (1..3) | Measure-Object).Count 
1   # By wrapping the array in a helper array, the original array was preserved.
```

That is, `, <collection>` creates a transient single-element helper array around the original collection so that the enumeration is only applied to the helper array, outputting the enclosed original collection as-is, as a single object.

A **conceptually clearer, but more verbose and *slower* approach is to use [`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6)**, which clearly signals the intent to output a collection *as a single object*.

```
PS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..3) | Measure-Object).Count 
1   # Write-Output -NoEnumerate prevented enumeration.
```

---

**Pitfall with respect to *visual inspection*:**

On outputting *for display*, the boundaries between multiple arrays are *seemingly* erased again:

```
PS> (1..2), (3..4) # Output two arrays without enumeration
1
2
3
4
```

That is, even though two 2-element arrays were each sent as a single object each, the output, through showing elements each on their own line, makes it look like a flat 4-element array was received.

A simple way around that is to *stringify* each array, which turns each array into a string containing a space-separated list of its elements.

```
PS> (1..2), (3..4) | ForEach-Object { "$_" }
1 2
3 4
```

Now it is obvious that two separate arrays were received.

---

<sup>[1] **What data types are enumerated**:

Instances of data types that implement the `IEnumerable` interface are automatically enumerated, but there are exceptions:

Types that also implement `IDictionary`, such as *hashtables*, are *not* enumerated, and neither are `XmlNode` instances.

Conversely, instances of `DataTable` (which doesn't implement `IEnumerable`) *are* enumerated (as the elements of their `.Rows` collection) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) and the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/43e0394d51b7ee8c5fa84f5308e27cec4f942672/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L515).

Additionally, note that stdout output from *external program* is enumerated *line by line*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As PowerShell "arrays" usually unroll in the [pipeline] and a using the pipeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) has a memory usages advantage (as each item is processed separately), I would change the question to:

### Slice a PowerShell *pipeline* into smaller batches

I have created a small [`Create-Batch`](https://github.com/iRon7/Create-Batch) function for this:

```
Install-Script -Name Create-Batch
```

*Example 1**

```
1..5 |Create-Batch -Size 2 |ForEach-Object { "$_" }
1 2
3 4
5
```

*Example 2**

```
Get-Process |Create-Batch |Set-Content .\Process.txt
```

This creates a single batch (array) containing all the itams
The result of this statement is the same as: `Get-Process |Set-Content .\Process.txt` but note that this appears (for yet unknown reason) about twice as fast.
See: [`#8270` Suggestion: Add a chunking (partitioning, batching) mechanism to Select-Object, analogous to Get-Content -ReadCount](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8270)