# Strange behavior for PowerShell Length after ForEach method

Tags: powershell

In [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#count-or-length-or-longlength) it's mentioned that `Length` is one alias for `Count`, however I found one case that they behave differently. Besides, if I replace `ForEach` method with `ForEach-Object`, the `Length` will emit 3. Can anyone explain this?

```
> (1..3).ForEach({$_}).Length
1
1
1
```

```
> (1..3).ForEach({$_}).Count
3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`.Length` and `.Count`** are aliases of one another and are so-called ***intrinsic members* (properties) that PowerShell adds to *most* objects**, in the interest of unified treatment of scalars and collections (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459795/45375) for background).

**The *exception* are objects of types that PowerShell treats as *collections***, i.e. objects that it automatically *enumerates* in the pipeline, which includes instances of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` that the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) returns.

**PowerShell does *not* add `.Length` and `.Count` properties to instances of what it considers collections, because it assumes that they have such properties *themselves***, type-natively, assumed to be implemented *efficiently* (rather than PowerShell having to perform the enumeration and counting the elements).

This is a reasonable assumption that *typically* holds for `.Count`, but *rarely* for `.Length` (arrays ([`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)) being the one notable example where `.Length` exists and returns the element count).

Thus, **it's generally better to use `.Count` rather than `.Length`.**

---

When you access `.Length` on an instance of a type that PowerShell considers a collection, yet that type has no such type-native property, PowerShell performs [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375):

- That is, it enumerates the collection and returns the *elements*' `.Length` property values.
- In your case, since the elements are *scalars* (single `[int]` objects), they *do* have the *intrinsic* `.Length` property, which in the case of a scalar always returns `1`.

Therefore:

```bash
(1..3).ForEach({$_}).Length
```

is effectively the same as:

```bash
(1..3).ForEach({ $_.Length })
```

The above explains the (`1, 1, 1`) output.
By contrast, the `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` does have a *type-native* `.Count` property, which returns the count of elements, as expected.

---

**Background information:**

Note:

- Only those types that PowerShell does *not* consider collections get the intrinsic `.Count` and `.Length` properties.
- Conversely, types that *are* considered collections may or may not have any, either, or both such properties *type-natively*, and in the absence of a type-native property [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) is performed instead.

  - Notable examples of types that have *neither* property type-natively are *lazy enumerables*; e.g., `[Linq.Enumerable]::Range(1,3).Count` yields `1, 1, 1`.

**Which .NET types PowerShell considers collections (enumerables) and therefore automatically enumerates in the pipeline:**

- Any **type that implements** the **[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) / [`` IEnumerable`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable-1)** .NET interface(s)

  - ***Except*** the following, which are *not* automatically enumerated:

    - [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) / [`` IDictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2), which notably includes `[hashtable]` (`@{ ... }`, as a literal) and its ordered cousin, [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) (`[ordered] @{ ... }`, as a literal)
    - [`XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode), the base type for `[xml]` ([`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument))
    - *Strings* ([`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)); note that `'foo'.Count` is `1` (the intrinsic property reflecting that a string is considered a *scalar* (single thing)), whereas `'foo'.Length` is `3` (the type-native property that returns the character count).
- ***Additionally*, [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable)** (which *itself* doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, only its `.Rows` property does).