# How to force array with one element to generate square brackets in json

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I'm trying to create a JSON array using:

```
$bodyObject = @(
    @{    
        'Username' = 'email0@email.com'        
    }
)

$body = $bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json
```

But the `$body` object doesn't contain the square brackets:

```
{
    "Username":  "email0@email.com"
}
```

If I add another element to the array, the code works perfectly:

```
$bodyObject = @(
    @{    
        'Username' = 'email0@email.com'        
    },
    @{    
        'Username' = 'email1@email.com'        
    }
)

$body = $bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json
<# Output:
[
    {
        "Username":  "email0@email.com"
    },
    {
        "Username":  "email1@email.com"
    }
]
#>
```

How can I get one element arrays to generate JSON containing the square brackets?

Comment: Change `$bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json` to `ConvertTo-Json $bodyObject`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That worked, thanks! Why not write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to pass the array positionally instead of through the pipeline:

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json $bodyObject
```

Reason why you don't see the array in the first example is because the [pipeline enumerates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3#one-at-a-time-processing).

Comment: Thanks for that. Btw I tried to Base64 decode the text on your profile but it came back with random chars. Is it Base64 encoded text?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner its gzip b64 ;)

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76478291/45375):

- The enumeration behavior of PowerShell's pipeline means that **a receiving command fundamentally cannot tell the difference between pipeline input that was provided as (a) a *single input object* or (b) as a *single-element array***.

  - That is, the following two commands *both* send a single `[int]` instance through the pipeline:

    - `(42 | ForEach-Object GetType).Name` -> `Int32`
    - `(@(42) | ForEach-Object GetType).Name` -> `Int32`
- By contrast, when passing input *as an argument*, the target command *can* make such a distinction - *if designed to do so* - and [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json) *does*.

  - However, it is *rare* for cmdlets to make this distinction - see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for a discussion.

---

As an alternative to passing input by argument, **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) introduced the 
`-AsArray` switch**, which requests that even a single input object (which may have been a single-element array originally) be treated as an *array* in its JSON representation.

```
# PS v7+ only; ditto for @(42) as input.
42 | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress # -> '[42]'
```

---

As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, you can **achieve the same outcome by ensuring that a given array - even if it contains just *one* element - is sent through the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) *as a whole***, which also works in *Windows PowerShell*.

- Note: While with `ConvertTo-Json` it's much simpler to pass an array as an *argument* to `ConvertTo-Json`, as shown in Santiago's answer, the techniques below may be of interest for commands that do *not* support passing array-valued arguments or support pipeline input only.

```
# Works in Windows PowerShell too.
# The unary form of the "," operator ensures that the array
# is sent *as a whole* through the pipeline.
, @(42) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress # -> '[42]'
```

The unary form of `,`, the [array constructor ("comma") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) constructs what acts as a *transient, auxiliary* array here:

- Its one and only element is the input array.
- When the pipeline *enumerates* this array, its one and only element - the array of interest - is sent *as a whole* through the pipeline.

There's a less obscure - but less efficient - alternative, using [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) with its `-NoEnumerate` switch:

```
# Works in Windows PowerShell too.
# -NoEnumerate prevents enumeration of the input array 
# and sends it through the pipeline as a whole.
Write-Output -NoEnumerate @(42) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress # -> '[42]'
```

Note:

- While the *result* is the same as with the v7+ `-AsArray` switch, the mechanism is different:
- With the auxiliary-array / non-enumeration technique, `ConvertTo-Json` truly receives an *array* as its one and only input object.
- With the v7+ `-AsArray` switch, when it receives a scalar (non-array) as its only input object, it still treats it as an array.
- If *multiple* input objects are received, `-AsArray` is a no-op, because even without this switch a JSON array must of necessity be output, given that `ConvertTo-Json` alway collects its input up front and then outputs a *single* JSON document for it.
- Do *not* use `-AsArray` in combination with an *argument* (as opposed to pipeline input), as that will result in a *nested* JSON array, at least as of this writing (PowerShell 7.3.4):

  ```
  ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress @(42) # !! -> '[[42]]'
  ```

  - [GitHub issue #10952](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10952) discusses this behavior, which may change.

---

##### The design rationale behind PowerShell's enumeration behavior:

PowerShell is built around ***pipelines*: data conduits through which objects *stream*, *one object at a time***.<sup>[1]</sup>

PowerShell commands output to the pipeline by default, and **any command can write *any number of objects*, including none - and that *number isn't known in advance***, because it can vary depending on arguments and external state.

- E.g., `Get-ChildItem *.txt` can situationally emit none, 1, or multiple objects.

Since the pipeline is just **a stream of objects of unspecified count**, there is **no concept of an *array* in the pipeline itself, neither on input nor on output**:

- On *input*, arrays (and most enumerables)<sup>[2]</sup> are enumerated, i.e. the elements are sent one by one to the pipeline. Therefore, there is no difference between sending a scalar (single object) and sending a single-element array through the pipeline, as demonstrated above.
- On *output*, multiple objects are simply output one at a time (though it is possible, but rare, to send an array (or other list-like type) as a whole, but it is then itself just another, single output object in the pipeline).

  - It is only when you *collect* a pipeline's output that arrays come into play, of necessity:

    - A single output object needs no container, and can just be received as itself.
    - Multiple objects need a container, and PowerShell automatically creates a `System.Object[]` array to collect the output objects in.

---

<sup>[1] You can introduce *buffering* of multiple objects with the [common -OutBuffer parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outbuffer), but the next command in a pipeline still receives the buffered objects one by one.</sup>

<sup>[2] For details, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375).</sup>

Comment: Is there any reason why the creators of Powershell throught it'd be good to have `(42 | ForEach-Object GetType).Name -> Int32` and `(@(42) | ForEach-Object GetType).Name -> Int32` do the same thing? No other language I know of acts like this, it's just confusing and unintuitive.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner, as for the design rationale: please see the bottom section I've just added to the answer.