# HashTable enumeration with unexpected results

Tags: powershell, hashtable, enumeration, enumerator

This may be a dumb question so please be kind LOL.  I'm trying to wrap my head around something I just ran into.

**First**

I have a HashTable that I can enumerate using the following:

```
$ht = [hashtable]@{"Key1"="Value1";"Key2"="Value2"}
$ht.GetEnumerator()

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1
Key2                           Value2
```

If I store this to a variable, it exists only for one call of the variable.

```
$KeyPairs = $ht.GetEnumerator()
$KeyPairs

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1
Key2                           Value2

$KeyPairs
# Nothing is returned as if $KeyPairs lost its value
```

Can someone help me understand why that is?

**Second**

Typically with a collection, I sometimes want to target a single item for testing (such as viewing properties of one instance), and I can use Select-Object or via index:

```
$array = @("Value1","Value2")
$array | select -first 1
Value1

$array[0]
Value1
```

The hashtable enumerator seems to only support the Select-Option, not the index.

```
$ht = [hashtable]@{"Key1"="Value1";"Key2"="Value2"}
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Select -first 1
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Select -first 1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1


($ht.GetEnumerator() | measure).count
2

($ht.GetEnumerator())[0]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1
Key2                           Value2
```

Can someone explain that as well?  Why can't I use the index option here?  $ht.GetEnumerator() returns a Dictionary collection, and when using Select -first 1, it returns a single DictionaryEntry, but when referencing the index, it returns both dictionary entries.

Comment: IMO, This is should split into multiple questions.

Comment: You can also reset the position with `$KeyPairs.Reset()`  and try to print `$KeyPairs` again to get the expected behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: This answer applies equally to situations where an API *directly* returns an enumerator object.

Using **`.GetEnumerator()` returns an *enumerator***<sup>[1]</sup> for the key-value pairs, which is **not the same as the *results of the enumeration***.

- An *enumerator* must be *iterated over* via its [`.MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) method in order to perform actual *enumeration*. However, you can let PowerShell do this for you, as shown below.

To get the desired behavior, **force enumeration via `@(...)`**, the [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), and **use the results**:

```bash
# Note the use of @(...), which collects the enumerated objects
# in an [object[]] array.

# Get an array of key-value pairs.
$KeyPairs = @($ht.GetEnumerator())

# Get the first key-value pair.
@($ht.GetEnumerator())[0]
```

Note:

- ***In the pipeline* it is PowerShell itself that *performs the enumeration* of an enumerator object**, which is why something like
  `$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { <# work with each key-value pair #> }` does work.
- In the pipeline, [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) / dictionaries, which are technically also *collections*, are *not* enumerated by default, unlike *list-like* collections such as arrays.<sup>[2]</sup> That is, hashtables / dictionaries are sent *as a whole* through the pipeline by default, which is why a call to `.GetEnumerator()` is needed to return an enumerator for their  *entries* (key-value pairs), which the pipeline then enumerates.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> $KeyPairs
> # Nothing is returned as if $KeyPairs lost its value
> ```

Because `$KeyPairs` contains an *enumerator*, it is *done* enumerating after the *first* enumeration that output to the pipeline (the display) implicitly performed, and therefore there's nothing left to enumerate on *re-invocation* - unless you call `$KeyPairs.Reset()` first.
However, note that not every enumerator is guaranteed to support `.Reset()` for *repeating* an enumeration - some enumerators  invariably perform *one-time-only* enumerations.

> ```bash
> ($ht.GetEnumerator())[0] # !! DOESN'T WORK
> ```

- An *enumerator* cannot be indexed into.
- PowerShell treats it like a *single object* (which it is) and falls back to *its own indexing*, where it allows even single objects (scalars) to be indexed for the sake of unified handling of collections and scalars; in that case, `[0]` is an effective *no-op*, simply returning the single object itself (similar to how `(42)[0]` and `(42)[-1]` are the same as `42`)

---

<sup>[1] Specifically, [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator) returns an object that implements the [`System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator) interface.</sup>

<sup>[2] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for which types PowerShell does and doesn't automatically enumerate in the pipeline.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @mklement0.  This was very helpful and the forced enumeration with @(. . .) solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

`$KeyPairs` in your example `$KeyPairs = $ht.GetEnumerator()` is a misleading name, **you do not have Key / Value pairs allocated in that variable**, what you have is an object of the type `HashtableEnumerator`, a type that implements the [`IDictionaryEnumerator` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator?view=net-7.0), this interface, basically is a *"contract"* that specifies how a hash table can and should be enumerated. One of the specifics of the implementation is that the instance **can be enumerated once** and, if you want to enumerate it again, you must call its [`.Reset()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset?view=net-7.0#system-collections-ienumerator-reset). This, as far as I know, is applicable for any type implementing the [`IEnumerator` interace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-7.0) (base interface for `IDictionaryEnumerator`).

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> $ht = @{'Key1' = 'Value1'; 'Key2' = 'Value2' }
PS ..\pwsh> $enum = $ht.GetEnumerator()
PS ..\pwsh> $enum

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1
Key2                           Value2

PS ..\pwsh> $enum.Reset()
PS ..\pwsh> $enum

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Key1                           Value1
Key2                           Value2
```

As for the second question:

> The hashtable enumerator seems to only support the `Select-Option`, not the index.

That is correct, enumerators don't implement [`IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-7.0) nor the implement an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers).

If you want to use indexing you must convert that `HashtableEnumerator` into a collection of [`DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=net-7.0) using `@($ht.GetEnumerator())`, in which case, **using a hashtable in the first place wouldn't make sense, it would lose its purpose**.

Or, a better approach would be to use an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0), this type supports **accessing by index and by key** and is as fast as a normal hashtable while performing look-ups:

```bash
$dict = [ordered]@{'Key1' = 'Value1'; 'Key2' = 'Value2' }
$dict[0]      # Value1
$dict.Keys[0] # Key1

# or, for a key / value pair:
[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]::new($dict.Keys[0], $dict[0])

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# Key1                           Value1
```

Comment: I don't know what happened to my comment here, but I'll post again.  Thanks Santiago!