# c# program to read sql to csv files

Tags: c#

this program going loop
and not resulting files with the data

```
namespace csv1
{
    class A
    {
        public static async Task<List<string>> sql_to_csv(string connectionString, string providerName, string tableName, string outputFilepath, Encoding outputFileEncoding, long maxNbOfRows, bool addHeaderRow = true, string separator = ";")
        {
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
            using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT top 10 * FROM table";
                long totalRecords = 0;
                long fileCount = 0;
                List<string> filesCreated = new List<string>();
                string filePattern = calculateFilePattern(outputFilepath);
                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                 //   if (reader == null || !reader.HasRows)
                 //       return filesCreated;//Table is empty
                                   
                    while (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        
                        string curFileName = string.Format(filePattern,++fileCount);
                       
                        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(curFileName))
                        {
                          

                            totalRecords += await _exportToSplittedCsv(reader, writer, maxNbOfRows, addHeaderRow, separator) ;
                            
                        }

                        filesCreated.Add(filePattern);
                    }
                }
                //You can return totalRecords or the list of files created or event the fileCount if you prefer
               return filesCreated;
            }
        }
        private static string calculateFilePattern(string path)
        {
            //The path already contains the Counter placeHolder on it
            if (path.Contains("{0"))
                return path;

            int extIndex = path.LastIndexOf('.');
            if (extIndex == -1)
                return path + "{0:00000}";
            else
                return path.Substring(0, extIndex) + "{0:00000}" + path.Substring(extIndex);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exports Database until reader has no more records or until maxNbOfRows is reached
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">System.Data.Common.DbDataReader used to read data from database</param>
        /// <param name="writer">Writer that will write CSV content in the current file</param>
        /// <param name="maxNbOfRows">Maximum number of rows to write on the output file</param>
        /// <param name="addHeaderRow">When true: first row in the CSV file will contain the Column names</param>
        /// <param name="separator">CSV field separator</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static async Task<long> _exportToSplittedCsv(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader, System.IO.StreamWriter writer, long maxNbOfRows, bool addHeaderRow, string separator)
        {
            long rowCount = 0;

            if (addHeaderRow)
            {
     
                await writer.WriteAsync(getColNames(reader, separator));
            await writer.WriteLineAsync();
           
            }


            while (await reader.ReadAsync() && (maxNbOfRows  < 1 || rowCount < maxNbOfRows))
            {
                //     await writer.WriteLineAsync();
          
                   
                   await writer.WriteLineAsync(buildCsvRow(reader, separator));

                ++rowCount;


            }
        await writer.FlushAsync();
            writer.Close();
            return rowCount;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Builds CSV row containing the column names
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">System.Data.Common.DbDataReader used to read data from database</param>
        /// <param name="separator">CSV field separator</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string getColNames(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader, string separator)
        {
            var rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                rowBuilder.Append(separator).Append(reader.GetName(i));
            }
            //We remove extra separator from the begin...
            return rowBuilder.Remove(0, 1).ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a CSV row containing a database row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">System.Data.Common.DbDataReader used to read data from database</param>
        /// <param name="separator">CSV field separator</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string buildCsvRow(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader, string separator)
        {
            var rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                //If you want to format DateTime to a specific value...
                /*switch (reader.GetDataTypeName(i))
                {
                    case : //The typename changes depending of the Database type...
                        DateTime dt = reader.GetDateTime(i);
                        if (dt == null)
                            rowBuilder.Append(separator);
                        else
                            rowBuilder.Append(separator).Append(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        break;
                    default:
                        rowBuilder.Append(separator).Append(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                }*/
                rowBuilder.Append(separator).Append(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
            }
            //We remove extra separator from the begin...
            return rowBuilder.Remove(0, 1).ToString();
        }




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            // replace these with your own values
            builder.DataSource = "xxxxx";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "xxxxxx";
            builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            string provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            Task task = sql_to_csv(builder.ConnectionString, provider, "table", "C:\\export_customerOrders{0:00000}.csv", Encoding.Default, 5, true, ",");
            task.Wait(360);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: The `hasRows` property does NOT advance the IDataReader. You should `while (reader.Read())` instead

Comment: thanks, loop issue gone, however exporting SELECT top 15 * FROM xxxxxx data to 3 csv files, I can see 5 rows in first file and second file, but third file returns nothing, seems flushing the data while loading.

Comment: You are waiting the task only for 360 ms... Maybe the 3rd file writing is not ended? You should wait for completion instead with **task.wait();**

Comment: You can also replace:
**await writer.WriteAsync(getColNames(reader, separator));
await writer.WriteLineAsync();** by:
**await writer.WriteLineAsync(getColNames(reader, separator));**

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Many thanks  TwiXter and  Cleptus.    This works perfectly fine after replacing with await WriteAsync.